# How to reuse XML layout

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In an app I'm making I display posts using the XML below. The thing is I need it to be able to be easily reused, right now each class that displays posts needs to have the XML so whenever I change one value I have to go through all the classes to change it for each page.

So my main question is, is it possible to move the FormatPosts method to a C# class called LayoutUtils so on each page's constructor I just use `LayoutUtils.FormatPosts` and it returns everything parsed or something, and have the XML in one class so If I change it, it updates it everywhere?

The XML code I use is;

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage *snip*>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextPostTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor = "Black" FontSize = "15"/>  
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Body}" TextColor = "Black"/>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0, 0, 0, 5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Likes}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LikeSource}" HeightRequest = "22" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="InvalidPostTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor = "Black" FontSize = "15"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="This post type is not supported in your current version!" TextColor = "Red" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0, 0, 0, 5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Likes}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LikeSource}" HeightRequest = "22" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:TweetTemplateSelector x:Key="TweetTemplateSelector"
                         TextPostTemplate="{StaticResource TextPostTemplate}"
                         InvalidPostTemplate="{StaticResource InvalidPostTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content >
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#1289A7">
        <ListView x:Name="PostListView" ItemsSource="{Binding PostObject}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TweetTemplateSelector}" HasUnevenRows="True" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I then bind the XML using this code;

```
     public static IList<PostObject> FormatPosts(Page page, INavigation navigation, string json)
    {
        IList<PostObject> Posts = new List<PostObject>() { };
        var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(json);

        foreach (var post in posts)
        {
            if (post.type == 0)
            {
                Posts.Add(new TextPost
                {
                    Name = post.name,
                    Body = post.body,
                    Likes = LayoutUtils.FormatCounter(post.Likes),
                    LikeSource = post.Liked == 1 ? "liked_icon.png" : "like_icon.png"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Posts.Add(new InvalidPost
                {
                    Name = post.name,
                    Likes = LayoutUtils.FormatCounter(post.Likes),
                    LikeSource = post.Liked == 1 ? "liked_icon.png" : "like_icon.png"
                });
            }
        }
        return Posts;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here.

1. You can either make a custom [Content View](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/) that you add wherever you're currently using the above code, which essentially contains all of the above code. This is the recommended approach, as you'll only manage everything regarding to this view in 1 file (well, technically 2, a xaml and cs code-behind)
2. Or you can make use of the [App.xaml](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/) class, and add the DataTemplates you've made above, in there. This will allow you to reuse them all over your app, the same as you do right now. The downside to this option is, you'll still have to write all the code-behind every time.